# Método FindOne do Mongoose está execultando em loop infinito

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

estou com o seguinte problema. Tenho um método FindOne que buscar se um usuário existe no banco de dados, de acordo com o usuário e senha. Porém quando executo o método - utilizando o insomnia, ele acaba ficando em loop infinito, enquanto eu não cancelar a requisição.

Código do método

```
// LOGIN - GET
    async login(req, res) {
        // Encriptando senha
        // let password = encriptacao(req.body.password)
        // console.log(password);

        // const user = await Usuario.findOne({ username: req.body.username, password: password })
        const user = await Usuario.findOne({ username: 'mateus', password: '133ed6f8476497d7a0a4239c2a68c19e' })
        console.log(user);

        if (user) {
            res.header('author', user.username)
            //res.header('logado', true)
            return res.redirect('/admin')
        } else {
            res.header('logado', false)
            return res.status(401).json({ status: 'error', cause: 'Usuário e/ou senha incorretos e/ou não existentes' }).send()
        }
    }
```

Resultado no console(do `console.log(user)`):

```
{
  _id: 5e9f8c195e983a2a4cbbb083,
  username: 'mateus',
  password: '133ed6f8476497d7a0a4239c2a68c19e',
  name: 'sousa',
  registerDate: 2020-04-22T00:13:13.792Z,
  __v: 0
}
{
  _id: 5e9f8c195e983a2a4cbbb083,
  username: 'mateus',
  password: '133ed6f8476497d7a0a4239c2a68c19e',
  name: 'sousa',
  registerDate: 2020-04-22T00:13:13.792Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

OBS: Só há um user e senha assim;
No console, fica em loop infinito, como eu disse

Atualização:
Removi o `res.redirect('/admin')`
E deu certo. Não fica em Loop infinito. Porém não estou entendeno o porque disso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, consegui resolver o problema. É o seguinte, como vemos, meu código após verificar se o user existe, ele manda criar dois headers e redireciona para a rota '/admin'. Então,  no método GET da rota admin, ele tenta ler os headers, e caso o header de "logado" não exista ou seja falso, ele manda para a página de login de novo. E como se trata de outra rota, o header nunca era setado. Daí, ficava no loop…

Código da rota "admin"

```
// PÁGINA ADMIN - GET
    async admin(req, res) {
        try {
            const total = await Post.count()
            const { page = 1 } = req.query
            const logado = req.headers.logado
            const author = req.headers.author
            console.log(logado + 'a');


            if (logado == true) {
                const posts = await Post.paginate({}, {
                    page,
                    limit: 10,
                    sort: {
                        'dateCreation': -1,
                    }
                })

                return res.render('admin',
                    { post: posts.docs, total, author }
                )
            }else {
                return res.redirect('/login')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.redirect('/login')
        }

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

É considerado uma boa prática ter try catch quando to utiliza async await. O que está a acontecer é que muito provavelmte o metodo `findOne` está a lançar uma exception que não está a ser resolvida.

Tenta com o seguinte código:

```
  async login(req, res) {
    try {
      const user = await Usuario.findOne({ username: 'mateus', password: '133ed6f8476497d7a0a4239c2a68c19e' })
      console.log(user);

      if (user) {
          res.header('author', user.username)
          //res.header('logado', true)
          return res.redirect('/admin')
      } else {
          res.header('logado', false)
          return res.status(401).json({ status: 'error', cause: 'Usuário e/ou senha incorretos e/ou não existentes' }).send()
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e.message, e.code);
      return res.status(500).json({message: e.message});
    }
  }
```

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado. Mas infelizmente não resolveu :(, continua o loop…

Comment: Aquilo a que estás a chamar de loop infinito é a página no teu navegador dar algum erro do tipo "ERROR CONNECTION TIMEDOUT" ou algo do genero correcto?

Comment: Não não, eu uso o insomnia para testar as rotas, dai quando faço a requisição - que vai executar esse método, ela funciona, porém fica em loop infinito. Ai só para quando eu clico em cancelar a requisição

Comment: O insonio funciona com o mesmo principio que um broser, faz um pedido HTTP para um endpoint, se não tiver uma resposta do servidor a tua ligação vai entrar em timeout. Como podes ter reparado o código dentro do bloco catch apenas tinha um console.log, ou seja, apenas ia imprimir o erro na consola sem te devolver uma HTTP response. Se puderes ver o que tens na consola podes confirmar que muito provavelmente vais ter la o erro da tua exception.